# Chat conversations tab's tooltip text is missing an "of"

Tags: bug, chat, tooltips, grammar, chat-bookmarks

I noticed an apparent bug in the text when I hover the "conversations" tab in a chat room, it looks like the text is a little grammatically wrong:

The text reads:

> a chronological list conversations in this room bookmarked by users

Looks like it meant to be:

> a chronological list **of** conversations in this room bookmarked by users

Not a major issue but I felt it should still be pointed out.

[image: screenshot of tooltip from conversations tab]

Comment: I checked the commit history, and two days from now this bug will have its sixth birthday. Congratulations, you may be the only person ever to read that tooltip :)

Comment: @balpha I feel like that's some sort of accomplishment, finding an almost 6-year-old bug. ;)

Comment: Lol, you read tooltips. ;)